# How does Windows API work?

Tags: c, winapi

It seems we are free to use Windows API simply by including header files needed. However, i couldn't make myself understand how this is possible given that header files do not have function definitions but declarations, which is supposed to be considered as an error in that it lacks implementation details. In what way does a compiler locate an implementation detail and map it into memory?

Comment: Windows has all of the functionality built in, and proves an API to it. There are libraries that are included that connect to that functionality. The headers simply provide definitions for those functions. The implementation is provided by Windows via DLLs. It might be a good idea to find a tutorial or book that explains these basics.

Comment: @KenWhite You mean to say that DLLs are automatically taken into account such that, in linkage process, the compiler gets all it needs? For it to make sense, header files have to make sure that the compiler know what DLL is needed. How is it done?

Comment: No, I mean that the header files provide the declarations, and the inclusion of the import libraries provide the linkage to the built-in DLL functionality. Again, it might be a good idea to find a tutorial. Use of DLLs and import libraries is basic information for using the Windows API, and it's available in lots of places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows API is implemented in DLLs that are installed when you install Windows. Those DLLs are in the System directory and have names like User32.dll, Kernel32.dll, etc.

As you correctly noted, the Windows API header files supplied with your compiler contain only the declarations. When your C program calls one of those functions (or any other function that's identified in a header file but not actually compiled with your project), the compiler places a record in the generated object file that says, in effect, "I need to call a function called `GetWindowRect` (or whatever the name of the function you called)."

The *linker* is what actually resolves the names. If you look at your linker options, you'll see that it's linking some libraries like User32.lib, Kernel32.lib, etc. Those libraries contain compiled functions that are little more than stubs--code that causes the corresponding DLL to be loaded, and then calls the function in the DLL.

It's a little bit more involved than that, but that's the general idea. In summary:

1. You include the Windows API header files.
2. Your code makes a call to one or more Windows API functions that are declared in those header files.
3. The compiler makes a note for the linker to resolve those API function calls.
4. The linker resolves the calls by finding the stub functions in the libraries that you specify on the linker command line.
5. At runtime, a call to one of those functions causes the corresponding DLL to be loaded, and then control is branched to the function in the DLL.

Comment: I have another question concerning your answer. You said that the compiled code in .lib causes DLLs to be loaded. However, i don't know why DLLs are necessary. In theory, i think the libs are enough to provide implementation details, aren't they? Is there any reason to wrap a binary code twice?

Comment: @user3647351: The implementation details of the Windows API functions are contained in the DLLs. The functions in the .lib files provide the bridge between your compiled code and the compiled code that's located in the DLLs.

Comment: DLLs are used so the implementations can be reused for multiple processes, and updates can be installed only once. @There are no functions in the import .lib files.  They contain references to the actual DLL functions. The linker puts those references into the IMPORTS table of the final executable.  When the executable is loaded into memory at runtime, the OS Loader patches the IMPORTS table with the addresses of the actual DLL functions. When your code calls a Win32 API function that was statically linked, it jumps directly into the DLL function.

Comment: Read [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format, Part 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) and [Part 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx)

Comment: Note that there are two kinds of .lib files; this kind, which bridge your application and a DLL, and static libraries, which contain actual code.  Many libraries (including the C runtime library) ship with both sorts, and you can choose which one to use.  The Windows API does not provide static libraries, because using static libraries would mean that you'd need to rebuild the application not only for every new version of Windows, but every time Microsoft released Windows updates.

Answer (score 2):

It works the same as any other library, for example C `stdlib` - your program only needs to 'know' the prototypes of functions (and thus the underlying symbol names). After compilation comes linking - that's when the symbols (function definitions) that are missing get 'linked' with a correct library.

Comment: However, we ever do not explicitly compile the source file needed to back up function declarations in header counterpart when using Windows API. I mean, how come does linkage come into play even if we don't have a appropriate source file that's needed?

Comment: Depends on the linker you use, if you don't have to add any special arguments and 'it just works' then the linker automatically links against certain .lib files for you.